# Application of Fokker-Planck equation in Ito calculus

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In http://markov.uc3m.es/2009/02/ito-calculus-for-the-rest-of-us/, [image] is derived. But I don't get this: after all, the process is defined as [image] - which means that $f(X,t)$ in this context is zero (or am I wrong here?). So how can this equation be derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, not an ounce of `(stochastic-calculus)` here, but the remark that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=2\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\implies\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}=2\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(2\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right).
$$
Since
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(2\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{y}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+2\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2},
$$
the result follows.

Comment: I get this part, but then $g(x,t) = a$, right? So, shouldn't it be $a^2$, not $a^2/2$? Where did I make mistakes?

Comment: Oh, but then looking at Wikipedia's notation makes me understand how one derives $a^2/2$... So I guess the link made an error there.